# Setting postgres environmental variables running image

Tags: postgresql, docker, kubernetes, skaffold

As [the documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres) shows, you should be setting the env vars when doing a `docker run` like the following:

```
docker run --name some-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD='foo' POSTGRES_USER='bar'
```

This sets the superuser and password to access the database instead of the defaults of `POSTGRES_PASSWORD=''` and `POSTGRES_USER='postgres'`.

However, I'm using Skaffold to spin up a k8s cluster and I'm trying to figure out how to do something similar. How does one go about doing this for Kubernetes and Skaffold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@P Ekambaram is correct but I would like to go further into this topic and explain the "whys and hows".

When passing passwords on Kubernetes, it's highly recommended to use encryption and you can do this by using secrets.

**Creating your own Secrets** ([Doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#creating-your-own-secrets))

To be able to use the secrets as described by @P Ekambaram, you need to have a secret in your kubernetes cluster.

To easily create a secret, you can also create a Secret from generators and then apply it to create the object on the Apiserver. The generators should be specified in a `kustomization.yaml` inside a directory.

For example, to generate a Secret from literals  `username=admin`  and  `password=secret`, you can specify the secret generator in  `kustomization.yaml`  as

```sh
# Create a kustomization.yaml file with SecretGenerator
$ cat <<EOF >./kustomization.yaml
secretGenerator:
- name: db-user-pass
  literals:
  - username=admin
  - password=secret
EOF
```

Apply the kustomization directory to create the Secret object.

```sh
$ kubectl apply -k .
secret/db-user-pass-dddghtt9b5 created
```

**Using Secrets as Environment Variables** ([Doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-environment-variables))

This is an example of a pod that uses secrets from environment variables:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: secret-env-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: mycontainer
    image: redis
    env:
      - name: SECRET_USERNAME
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: mysecret
            key: username
      - name: SECRET_PASSWORD
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: mysecret
            key: password
  restartPolicy: Never
```

Source: [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets) and [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/).

Answer (score 1):

Use the below YAML

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: postgres
spec:
  serviceName: postgres
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
       name: postgres
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: postgres
          image: postgres:11.2
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
          env:
            - name: POSTGRES_DB
              value: "sampledb"
            - name: POSTGRES_USER
              value: "postgres"
            - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
              value: "secret"
          volumeMounts:
            - name: data
              mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql
      volumes:
        - name: data
          emptyDir: {}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: postgres
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - port: 5432
  selector:
    name: postgres
```